# Появляются двойные квадратные скобки в Firebase JAVA

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

Мне надо получить ArrayList с базы данных Firebase. Суть такая, создается некое мероприятие и при его создании автоматически добавляется e-mail пользователя в базу данных Firebase. Потом другие пользователи могут туда вступать и к предыдущим e-mailам добавляется текущий. Проблема в том, что первый e-mail создатели отображается и читается корректно в Firebase: "test@mail.ru" и добавляется в ArrayList. Последующие же имеилы добавляются уже примерно так: "[[test@mail.ru, test1@mail.ru], test3@mail.ru]". Ощущение что элементы списка сливаются в один.

```
 Party currentParty = new Party(name, nums, R.drawable.party_1,location);
        //currentParty.setUsersList(firebaseUsers);
        usersMails = new ArrayList<>();
        usersMails.add(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        currentParty.setUsersMails(usersMails);
        reference.setValue(currentParty.getUsersMails());
```

На этом этапе все работает корректно. То есть метод getusersMails() возвращает лист как надо, без двойных квадратных скобок.
Вот тут в адаптере уже появляется эта проблема с двойными квадратными скобками:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PartyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Party party = parties.get(position);
        holder.peoples.setText(party.getNumMans());
        holder.name.setText(party.getName());
        holder.image.setImageResource(party.getImagePath());

        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PartyItem.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageUrl", party.getImagePath());
                intent.putExtra("count", party.getNumMans());
                intent.putExtra("nameParty", party.getName());
                intent.putExtra("location_party", party.getLocation());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("partyUsers", party.getUsersMails());




                //intent.putExtra("partyPath", party.getPartyPath());

                context.startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

    }
```

Файл Party.java:

```
package com.example.tusaproject;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Party {

    private String name;
    private String numMans;
    private int imagePath;
    private String location;
    private ArrayList <FirebaseUser> usersList;
    private ArrayList<String> usersMails;
    private String PartyPath;

    public String getPartyPath(){
        return PartyPath;
    }
    public void setPartyPath(String path){
        PartyPath = path;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUsersMails() {
        return this.usersMails;
    }

    public void setUsersMails(ArrayList<String> usersMails) {
        this.usersMails = usersMails;
    }

    public int getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(int imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


    /*public String getPartyUsers() {
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

        for(FirebaseUser user: usersList){
            users.add(user.getEmail());


        }
        return users.toString();
    }*/


    public List<FirebaseUser> getUsersList() {

        return usersList;
    }

    /*public List<String> getUsersNames(){
        usersList.
    }*/

    public void setUsersList(ArrayList<FirebaseUser> usersList) {
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    Party(String name, String numMans, int imagePath, String location){

        this.name = name;
        this.numMans = numMans;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.location = location;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumMans() {
        return numMans;
    }

    public void setNumMans(String numMans) {
        this.numMans = numMans;
    }

}
```

Вроде все правильно описал, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Где-то происходит преобразование списка в строку и потом она добавляется в новый список как элемент, а не конвертируется обратно в список. В приведённом коде я не вижу где это может происходить

Comment: @woesss мне кажется я нашел есть такая строчка: ```ArrayList<String> getUsers = new ArrayList<>();
                        getUsers.add(dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue().toString());
                        party1.setUsersMails(getUsers);   party.add(party1)``` если выводить в лог значение dataSnapshot, он выводится корректно, но при добавлении в лист появляются еще одни скобки.

Comment: Да - здесь вы всех `"users"` объединяете в одну строку и вставляете в список одним элементом. Я не особо знаю SDK файербазы, думаю должно быть как-то так: `getUsers.addAll((List<String>) dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue());` - если это не правильно, то смысл в том что нужно получить из базы именно список `List` и добавить его методом `addAll`

Comment: @woesss Это помогло, друг, спасибо большое !!!! Сколько же я мучился с этой проблемой, благодаря тебе мое портфолио почти готово, обнимаю) !!